# Angular time out due to Spring boot service down

Tags: angular, timeout, loading, subscribe

My angular frontend made a POST http request. But the back-end Spring Boot service is down(not started) so I can see below error appearing on the Chrome console after a few seconds:

POST https://localhost:8080/report/data net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Error callback has been added to stop the spinning but it seems this situation cannot be controlled so it keeps spinning. Here's my code:

```
this.dataService.getData(detailParam).subscribe(
  (responseData: any) => {
    this.closeLoading();
    console.log(success);
  },
  (error) => {
    this.closeLoading();
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

How can I catch the net::ERR_TIMED_OUT error and stop the loading?

Comment: What does "Error callback has been added to stop the spinning but it seems this situation cannot be controlled so it keeps spinning" mean?  You should also post the code for `closeLoading`

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs operator `finalize` in order to prevent duplicated code like this:

```
dataService.getData(`detailParam`).pipe(finalize(() => closeLoading())).subscribe(
  (responseData: any) => {
    console.log('success');
  },
);
```

It's also better since passing multiple functions to `subscribe` function is deprecated:

> @deprecated — Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an observer argument. Signatures taking separate callback arguments will be removed in v8.

Nevertheless your code should work if `this.dataService.getData(detailParam)` does indeed emit an error. Maybe you can provide this code in order to find problems in this implementation.